# Can Middleman or Jekyll handle data relationships?

Tags: data-structures, foreign-keys, jekyll, relationship, middleman

One of my sites is static in the sense that the content is almost never updated. It was initially handcrafted with HTML+CSS+javascript and ran for more than 15 years with no need for maintenance! A few years ago I re-built the site with Rails with some more features, but I struggle with the need to keep up with the new versions of Rails; the initial build was with Rails 3, then I updated to Rails 4 and more recently to Rails 5 - updates necessary just to keep the site up and running. As much as I like Rails, I really don't want to spend time on updates on this particular site, and am thinking of using a static site generator to rebuild the site, but I'm not sure if they can handle my data structures.

The application involves just 8-9 models classes (and MySQL-tables), but with foreign keys to handle has_many and has_and_belongs_to_many relationships. I could export my database to JSON or YAML with id attributes for all records, but I  wonder if static site generators like Middleman or Jekyll will be capable of handling these relationships. I quick look through tutorials only shows very simple data structures involving key-value.

Comment: I can't answer the question as to *how* to setup your data structures without knowing more about your existing `has_many` et al structures. But I feel confident that if the site was built with flat HTML/CSS/JS files at one point, a static generator would do. Do you have a link to a git repo or the live site?

Comment: Without going into all the details: one part of the site deals with music recordings. A recording belongs_to a recording_set and a recording_set has_many recordings. There are also playlists and a recording has_and_belongs_to_many playlists... So I guess that when representing such objecs in JSON I would have to include object ids as one key-value pair and has_many would be represented by a "has_many" key with an array of ids as the value.

Comment: In the end I decided to go down a different path, and instead of using a static generator I used wget with the parameters proposed here: https://www.guyrutenberg.com/2014/05/02/make-offline-mirror-of-a-site-using-wget/ plus a small script that recursively makes some minor fixes, such as removing login links. The one tricky thing was to handle the language switching, which relies on a session variable in the Rails application - I fixed this by adding a locale parameter to all the link_to's. With this I can recreate a static site with 900 pages in about 2 minutes on a MacBook Pro.